# Flex Custom Component Communication

Tags: apache-flex, communication, components

What is the best practice in terms of communication (variable usage ann method calls) between custom components developed using mxml.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Flash's built-in Event mechanism, which has no external dependencies.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_01.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement one of the frameworks mentioned here: [Flex MVC Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/flex-mvc-frameworks). A proper architecture will allow you to communicate between components more easily. I use pureMVC in my current project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

PureMVC is pretty solid. It take a bit to get familiar with the design philosophy. But once you are set up it is pretty easy to code against and makes your project easy to grow and extend with solid MVC design principles.

The main thing about PureMVC is its concept is a concept of Notifications. You can pass around various objects in a simplified way throughout the system.

For an overview of PureMVC checkout

http://puremvc.tv

http://puremvc.org/

If you would like some more specific code examples or have specific questions let me know.