# Adobe Air (Flex or Html) Application Architecture

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, flex4

I have no experience with Adobe Air/Flex and want to know, are there some principles (design patterns) for developing Adobe Air/Flex applications? 
Thanks.

Comment: You looking for visual design patterns or application architecture patterns?

Comment: Only application architecture patterns, because I need to investigate( create some demo application) and I want to create using best practices.

Comment: In general I want to read best practices of development application using Flex and running it on Air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex applications are normally developed using an MVC framework. These frameworks are built on best practices and design patters and determine the (micro) architecture of your Flex app. There are plenty of MVC frameworks available for Flex, see this discussion for a comparison:

[Flex MVC Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/flex-mvc-frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no hard code rules. Just as, if a J2EE becomes too huge and complex you consider using a framework, similarly it will be the case for Flex. If you feel confident that your application size will be within your limits, don't use any framework.

If however, you want to use a framework, there are various choices with some of the best being, Parsley, Cairngorm 2.0, Swiz, PureMVC. However, which framework you should use depends upon your application. If you want to develop an Enterprise app, where you are hitting dataservices to fetch data now and then, use Parsley or Cairngorm 2.0, though if I were you I would prefer to use Parsley.

One important thing you need to take care of though is performance in Flex. Similar things apply to AIR as well.