# What does a web designer need to migrate to Flex quickly?

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flex3, flex4, user-experience

**What does a web designer need to migrate to Flex quickly?** 

A: tell me how I can get good fast

B: tell me why it would be unrealistic to learn Flex quickly

I want here both sides of it. Maybe web designers are not qualified, I'd
honestly like to know what it would take.
Thanks,

TELL ME WHAT I NEED
• Projects I need to complete in Flex
• Tutorials
• Key concepts
• Other technologies in a nutshell (webservices, SOAP, AJAX, HTML5 etc.)
MY SKILLS
• I code JavaScript (including HTML, CSS, XML, not much AJAX)
• Flash (hand code ActionScript 3.0 in classes, reasonable OPP skills) 
• I'm a designer 'no computer science degree'

---

This Flex reference should include everything needed for beginning Adobe Flash Builder 4

Comment: I'm just curious, how long did it take you to get "good" at what you're doing today?

Comment: It took a year for my design skills to mature, but I've done it for 7+ years. Long story, but I've been in development for 1.5 yrs, but only code ActionScript and JavaScript (with jQuery, HTML, CSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, the tenor of your post is a bit irritating.  Nothing worth doing comes easily or without some level of work.  "How can I get good fast?" implies you either don't have time or don't possess patience to do things right.  I doubt that's the case, however, and thus here are a few thoughts to your questions/bullet points:

> A: tell me how I can get good fast

I don't know what *you* know, and thus cannot tell you how long it will take you to become a solid Flex developer.  If you want to get good, you'll probably need at least *some* time; if you want to be fast, you can pick Flex up rather quickly, and your application may end up a buggy mess.  Depending on your definition of "fast" (and what you already know, of which, as I've said, I'm completely ignorant), you'll probably have to take your pick between the two.

Growth in any area usually comes with experience, instruction from superiors, and learning from ones' mistakes.  Getting "good" quickly is a concept which doesn't take these into account.

Your knowledge of Javascript, CSS, and design will certainly help, and I don't want to denigrate your current experience.  Seven years of design is outstanding and a great gateway to Flex.  Those skills, however, likely came with time and effort, and you should expect the same with most new technologies.

> B: tell me why it would be unrealistic to learn Flex quickly

Of course you can learn Flex quickly.  I picked it up in a few days, and have spent the last 2 years of my life writing Flex applications full-time.  I consider myself well past proficient, and I still have quite a bit to learn.  The basics aren't terribly difficult (esp. since you have ActionScript experience).  Learning enough to be good, however, creates an explosion of new material to cover.  Consider these questions:

- Do you know how to architect a web application?  Not just assembling a quick and dirty web-page with a few basic controls -- do you know how to build a full-fledged web application which is *extensible*, *scalable*, and *robust* in its communication with a remote data server?
- Are you working with established data servers, or do you have to implement your own?
- Do you know how to manage large data sets efficiently?
- Do you know solid software design/development techniques and principles (DRY, YAGNI, KISS) and how to implement them in your code?

If you can't answer these questions (or answer them negatively), you probably have a way to go.  If you can answer them positively, you're at least on the right track.  There's still a plethora of things to know about Flex (some listed below), and each one will take some time to pick up.

> • Projects I need to complete in Flex

This question is a bit vague.  If you're referring to tutorials, you're repeating yourself (see your next bullet point).  If you're asking what applications will facilitate *writing* Flex apps (e.g. FlashBuilder 4), you haven't done enough homework.  If you're asking what programs we think you should write, you're asking the wrong people.  See my next point...

> • Tutorials

There are [many tutorials](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) for Flex development.  Start with a basic [Hello World](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/flex/flex4/flex4-hello-world.html) program and add simple features to the page (e.g. user controls, multiple MXML and ActionScript files, packages, styles, etc.).  You said you're a Javascript developer with HTML and CSS: why not attempt to rewrite one of your previous applications in Flex?

We don't know what topics you need to cover because we don't necessarily know what you'll be doing in Flex.  If you never plan on performing HTTP requests, you probably don't need to learn this functionality (at least not immediately).  If you will never work with server-side notifications to your app, BlazeDS and LiveCycle Data Services might not be important.

> • Key concepts

Man, where to start?  [Data binding](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_2.html), [Code behind patterns](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstarts/building_components_using_code_behind.html), [MXML vs ActionScript](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/MXML+vs+ActionScript+3.0), [Flex Skinning](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSA95C9644-B650-4783-B5C0-D2C7F95A23E3.html), [working with XML](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html), [MVC frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/flex-mvc-frameworks), the list goes on.  No list of "key concepts" is going to make you good fast.

> • Other technologies in a nutshell
>   (webservices, SOAP, AJAX, HTML5 etc.)

Here are a few things you might want investigate, depending on your needs:

- [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS)
- [LiveCycle Data Services](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/)
- [Flex and HTTP](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html)
- [Asynchronous Requests in Flex](http://kuwamoto.org/2007/04/25/asynchronous-calls-explained/)
- [Mobile Application Development](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/mobile/)

---

My recommendation is to start with the basics, and see what you're up against.  Build a "Hello world" app and extend it to include various other features.  Then assess what you hope to build with Flex, and how you expect to retrieve data from a back-end server.  These two points will help you decide what you'll need to learn next.  From there you can research each new topic you're trying to address and how to do it correctly.

Comment: I'm excited. This covers everything. Thanks @bedwyr