# Comparison between Mate, Swiz and Robotlegs frameworks for Flex development

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mate, robotlegs, swiz

My company is willing to reffactor its biggest and heaviest project introducing some kind of framework. Are there good online source/issue/blogpost with comparison of these 3 frameworks - [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/), [Swiz](http://swizframework.org/) and [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/)?

Comment: I voted to close; as I don't feel anything productive can come from such a question.  The approach I would recommend is: First define what problems you nned to solve to implement your solution.  Then evaluate the frameworks to see if they will help you solve those problems or hinder you.

Comment: You're also missing [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/), probably the most widely used framework for enterprise applications.

Comment: This is an solicitation for opinions, not a question.  To turn it into a question you could say "we need to do X, Y, Z" - can someone tell me a framework that suits these specific needs?  Be prepared for an answer in the form of "all of them"  =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a comparison is the way to go.  They all have strength and weaknesses.  It all comes down to what you're trying to accomplish.

With that said, my 2 personal choices are RobotLegs and Parsley.  RobotLegs is good for small to medium size application since it's easy to learn and use.  Parsley is more robust and adds a lot more features than RobotLegs, which is why its been used in the world's largest flex applications.  From your description, it seems this is a large project, then I would recommend Parsley, but maybe you don't need all of it's features.

Best thing you can do is try both and see which one fits best.

Answer (score 2):

You have tried googling, right?  A quick google turned up numerous pages doing comparisons.  Why those 3 frameworks?  What about Cairngorm or Parsley?

I ended up using Robotlegs because I liked that it was minimal and I like dependency injection via metadata (being a Spring user with Java).

The other question is why refactor to add a framework?  What is the expected benefit?  If you don't have an expected benefit, why do it?

Comment: I love RobotLegs too, it doesn't get in my way. However I've heard great things about Parsley as well.

Comment: Cairngorm 2 is a POS.  Cairngorm 3 is just Parsley extensions.  Plus, I think the question of 'why refactor if you don't need to' is a good one, but from my experience, anytime a Flex app has more than 2 developers or starts to get big, architecture and organization is a very big issue because of the 'view based' language.  IMO, adding a framework to this kind of project will add a lot of value (speed, simplicity, faster development) is done properly.

Answer (score 1):

My [Introduction to Flex Application's Architectures](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2011/09/13/introduction-to-flex-application%E2%80%99s-architecture-redux/) could be of help, because in this article instead of comparing the frameworks I list the common problems all architectural frameworks need to address as well with some code snippets on how the different frameworks approach the solutions. Understanding the common problems is crucial when it comes to understand why a certain frameworks is designed in that certain way.

Answer (score 0):

- A good starting point: [Adobe article about different Flex frameworks](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_framework.html)
- [Answer why Mate would be the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/flex-mvc-frameworks/37566#37566)
- [Article about different Flex frameworks](http://www.anandvardhan.com/2008/11/13/popular-flex-frameworks/)
- [Article about which framework to choose](http://www.wetfeetblog.com/flex-frameworks-puremvc-mate-cairngorm-robotlegs/297)

It seems that there aren't a lot of resources out there covering Robotlegs.

Comment: The "Answer why Mate would be the answer" is severely outdated.  At the time Mate was the best answer, but it's still view based and has a lot of issues in itself.  The Adobe article is also outdated.